# What are the main differences between sparse autoencoders and convolution autoencoders?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, autoencoders

What are the main differences and similarities between sparse autoencoders and convolution autoencoders?

When should one be preferred over the other? What are their applications?

(References are welcome. Somehow I was not able to find any comparisons of these autoencoders although I looked in a few textbooks and searched for material online. I was able to find the descriptions of each autoencoder separately, but what I am interested in is the comparison.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Sparse auto-encoders** (SAEs)](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder.pdf) are auto-encoders that impose constraints on the parameters so that they are *sparse* (i.e. zero or close to zero). This can be achieved in different ways. For example, you can train an auto-encoder with [a loss function that includes a penalty term](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3313-sparse-deep-belief-net-model-for-visual-area-v2.pdf) (to constraint the parameters to be close to zero or zero) or you e.g. [set the smallest activations to zero](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5663.pdf).

**Convolution auto-encoders (CAEs)** are auto-encoders that use the convolution operation. So, they can be viewed as the auto-encoder version of convolutional neural networks. For this reason, they are particularly suited to compress and reconstruct images. The authors of the original paper, [Stacked Convolutional Auto-Encoders for Hierarchical Feature Extraction](http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/icann2011stack.pdf), train them with gradient descent and back-propagation by minimizing the mean squared error, so there's e.g. no penalty term, but you can probably combine SAEs with CAEs.

Of course, you could say that CAEs are *sparse* with respect to the traditional auto-encoder (in the same way that you can say that CNNs are sparse with respect to fully connected neural networks), so, in this sense, CAEs are also sparse auto-encoders.